# How to access hidden buttons and click them

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, greasemonkey

I am trying to make a web page easier to use. At the moment, there is a drop down menu with a 'Delete' button. When I inspect, it looks like this:

```
<a title="" class="ajax-command" command="deletePost" href="#">Delete</a>
```

Is there any way I can execute this somehow? I am trying to create a new button that executes this command without the need of the dropdown. It is part of a set of buttons under this dropdown menu:

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dLabel">
                        <li class="item">
```

I have tried just replicating the click of the drop down selection, but I can't get it to work. Any help would be great!

Comment: which ajax command? you've shown HTML ... the j in ajax means javascript

Comment: a pure guess ... `document.querySelector('.ajax-command[command="deletePost"]).click();`

Comment: Oh!!! This worked! Thanks man!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simulate the click event on the link, it doesn't matter that it's hidden. I'll demonstrate this here by writing script that clicks *meta* link in hidden stackoverflow dropdown to the left:

[image: image description]

// Straight from MDN

```
var evt = new MouseEvent("click", {
  bubbles: true,
  cancelable: true,
  view: window
});

var cb = document.querySelectorAll("div.js-help-dialog li:nth-child(3) a.js-gps-track");

var canceled = !cb[0].dispatchEvent(evt);
```

This is what you should do. If you try to run their AJAX request you will find yourself re-inventing half of the whole application frontend.

Comment: Thanks for the great answer! I tried changing your code to suit my environment, but I couldn't get it to work; I keep getting:

Failed to construct 'MouseEvent': member view is not of type Window.

Comment: It looks like I got this working using the earlier comment, but for future reference, I'd like to know how to solve that member view issue as this looks super useful. Thanks!

Comment: @user1262935 `window` normally refers to global scope in browsers. If it's undefined or redefined, you should expect problems. But I think you can omit the whole `view: window` part, because it is not needed for this. **edit** just tested and it works well even with just `new MouseEvent("click")`

Answer (score 3):

jquery solution

```
$(".ajax-command[command='deletePost']").click()
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, but this doesn't work for some reason.

Comment: Maybe the `jQuery` isn't available. Or maybe it loads after your script loads. Or maybe it only works for jQuery click handlers.